# NPGSQL Drivers and Azure Database for SQL - Hyperscale Citus compatibility

Tags: azure, driver, npgsql, citus

We are migrating our Postgresql v10 (Linux) database to Azure and due to the timeframe involved would prefer not to change our current use of the npgsql driver in our apps.

Has anyone had any experience here? Can we utilize our use of that driver with very little or no changes to our code?

The one thing I'm aware of is that queries must use the shard column to help the Citus coordinator distribute to the right node. Anything else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have no personal experience with Citus, but as far as I know, Citus is supposed to be extremely compatible with PostgreSQL - definitely at the wire protocol level - and so general PostgreSQL drivers (like Npgsql) are supposed to work fine with it.

You may definitely need to change the way you're doing things at a higher level (e.g. sharding), but at the low-level database driver level Npgsql should be OK.

Comment: That is what we are hoping...I'm deploying a basic Citus now and plan to get data in there to test. Thank you!